# Artifactory: x509 certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: azure-devops, artifactory, jfrog-cli

Our working environment is Azure DevOps. We actually use PowerShell scripts to upload our artifacts to Artifactory.

Right now we are trying to download those artifacts using the Artifactory Service Connection in Azure DevOps, but not the PowerShell script. So now we are having the error

> [error] Post https://art..... : x509 certificate signed by unknown authority

How can we solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are accessing Artifacory via HTTPS and with a Self-signed certificate therefore the Artifactory service connection is not trusting the certs. I would recommend referring to this JFrog [Wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension#ArtifactoryAzureDevOpsExtension-NotUsingaPublicCA(CertificateAuthority)?) and by adding the certs to the trusted directory of the JFrog CLI which is used in most of the Artifactory Azure tasks.

Comment: I did that. I referred the wiki and provided the required certificate in the security/certs folder of my jfog in my Agent Machine and it did not work. Any other workarounds is appreciated.